# How to allow docker sibling container to bind subdirectory from existing volume

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I want to know how I can allow a "child" (sibling) docker container to access some subdirectory of an already mounted volume. As an explanation, this is a simple setup:

I have the following Dockerfile, which just installs Docker in a Docker container:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

I have the following data directory on my host machine

```
/home/user/data/
                data1.txt
                subdir/
                       data2.txt
```

Build the parent image:

```
[host]$> docker build -t parent .
```

Then run the parent container:

```
[host]$> docker run --rm --name parent -it -v /home/user/data/:/data/ -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock parent
```

Now I have a running container, and am "inside" the new container. Since I have the docker socket bound to the parent, I am able to run docker commands to create "child" containers, which are actually sibling containers. The data volume has been successfully mapped:

```
[parent]$> ls /data/
subdir   data1.txt
```

Now I want to create a sibling container that can only see the subdir directory:

```
[parent]$> docker run --rm --name child -it -v /data/subdir/:/data/ ubuntu
```

This creates a sibling container, and I am successfully "inside" the container, however the new data directory is empty. My assumption is because the volume I tell it to use "/data/" is mapped by the host to a directory that doesn't exist on the host, rather than using the volume defined when running the parent.

```
[child]$> ls /data/
<nothing>
```

What can I do to allow this mapping to work, so that the child can create files in the subdirectory, and that the parent container can see and access these files? The child is not allowed to see data1.txt (or anything else above the subdirectory).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Sibling" container is the correct term, there is no direct relationship between what you have labeled the "parent" and "child" containers, even though you ran the `docker` command in one of the containers.

The container with the docker socket mounted still controls the `dockerd` running on the host, so any paths sent to `dockerd` via the API will be in the hosts scope.

There are `docker` commands where using the containers filesystem does change things. This is when the `docker` utility itself is accessing the local file system. `docker build` `docker cp` `docker import` `docker export` are examples where `docker` interacts with the local file system.

#### Mount

Use `-v /home/user/data/subdir:/data` for the second container

```
docker run --name parent_volume \
  -it --rm -v /home/user/data:/data ubuntu

docker run --name child_volume \
  -it --rm -v /home/user/data/subdir:/data ubuntu
```

The processes you run need to be careful with what is writing to data mounted into multiple containers so data doesn't get clobbered.

Comment: Just to be clear, would I be correct in saying you can't do this with named volumes? e.g. 
    
    1. docker volume create --name data
    
    2. docker run --name parent_volume
      -it --rm -v data:/data ubuntu

    3. docker run --name child_volume
      -it --rm -v data/subdir:/data ubuntu

Comment: @RightOfZen Correct. Named volumes are stored on the host and explicitly separated by their id/name on the file system.