# Using mount paths from the outer container when nesting containers

Tags: docker

I am using an executor for data pipelines that can run processes and create required Docker containers according to pipeline scripts. It creates and runs bash scripts that also create docker run commands. For CI purposes I placed it in another container and mounted the docker socket (-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock). The problem is that the binding during the run command of the inner docker also mounts paths from the main machine, and not the outer container.

When running the container within a container with -v foldX:foldY, is there a way to make foldX be taken from the outer container, and not the main filesystem?

Comment: There is not.  There is no such thing as an "outer container"; the "inner" container doesn't know that another container launched it, and host-filesystem bind-mount paths always are interpreted by the Docker daemon in its host environment.

Comment: [How to allow docker sibling container to bind subdirectory from existing volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46924872/how-to-allow-docker-sibling-container-to-bind-subdirectory-from-existing-volume) is a similar case (though involving a bind mount in the "outer" container).